# Linear program with $\max$ function in the objective that may lead to unboundedness

Tags: optimization, linear-programming

I am trying to solve the following linear program

$$\text{minimize} \quad \color{grey}{\text{(some cost function)}} - 24 \max(0,x-24)$$

I introduce a dummy variable $t$ such that $t \geq x-24$ and $t \geq 0$.  I realized that if the variable $t$ is indeed greater than $0$, then it needs to be bounded above by some number, and the only appropriate number for my model has to be $x-24$ (due to the definition of $\max(0,x-24)$ being the excess quantity in my model). In other words, $t$ has to be exactly equal to $x-24$ if $x > 24$ or $0$.

I do not know how to work around this problem.  Could anyone give some ideas? I hope I explain it well and any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you sure the objective is convex?

Comment: Yes, I am pretty sure, as it is a basic cost function that appears in numerous scientific articles. However, these articles do not publish the technical details on solving the model

Comment: @FarahFai:  $ - 24 \cdot \max(0, x - 24) $ is a concave function.

Comment: Why not use [CVXPY](http://www.cvxpy.org)? Just use function `pos` and let CVXPY worry about the rest.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo This is the first time I heard about CVXPY.  Maybe you know how to tackle the problem so I can implement it on Matlab??

Comment: @FarahFai If you have MATLAB, you can use [CVX](http://cvxr.com/cvx/). Take a look at [this](http://web.cvxr.com/cvx/doc/advanced.html?highlight=maximum#adding-new-functions-to-the-atom-library).

Comment: @Rodrigo de Azevedo CVX also has a function, pos. But it is convex, so minus it is concave, so CVX will reject it (I presume CVXPY would as well)/  Perhaps it can be handled by suitable combining with "some cost function:, which we haven't been shown, or some other formulation. Otherwise, I believe binary variables could be used, with suitable CVX version/solver. applying a big M approach to modeling this, which requires upper and lower bounds on x. Or better yet, use YALMIP, which will automatically model the max and create the MILP (presming everything else is linear) and call a MILP solver.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, you will need to introduce a binary variable. This requires have a valid lower bound $L$ and upper bound $U$ on the value of $x$. Given these bounds, introduce a binary variable $z\in\{0,1\}$. Then the constraints

$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
y\leqslant Uz\\
y\leqslant x-L(1-z)\\
y\geqslant0\\
y\geqslant x
\end{array}\right.
$$
will ensure that $y=\max\{0,x\}$. To see that this is true, consider two cases. If $z=0$, then $x\leqslant0$. The constraints become
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
y\leqslant 0\\
y\leqslant x-L\\
y\geqslant0\\
y\geqslant x
\end{array}\right.
\Longrightarrow
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
y=0\\
x\geqslant{L}\ (\text{redundant})\\
x\leqslant0
\end{array}\right.
$$
Otherwise, if $z=1$, then $x\geqslant0$, and the constraints become
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
y\leqslant U\\
y\leqslant x\\
y\geqslant0\\
y\geqslant x
\end{array}\right.
\Longrightarrow
\left\{
\begin{array}{l}
y=x\\
y=x\leqslant{U}\ (\text{redundant})\\
y=x\geqslant0
\end{array}\right.
$$

See [this helpful blog](https://orinanobworld.blogspot.com/2011/01/max-and-min-functions-in-mip.html) for a more general explanation.

Comment: Thanks! but how would this affect my objective function?

Comment: If you add these constraints, then your objective function is $\min\text{ (some cost function) }-24y$ (after some easy modifications to make it $max\{0,x-24\}$ instead of $\max\{0,x\}$